# Method undefined for type Java

Tags: java, types, undefined, classification, weka

Having real trouble figuring out where i'm going wrong on this one. Building a system using WEKA in java to study associations and am trying to implement the Apriori algorithm. Currently this is the code:

```
package model;

import weka.associations.*;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;

public class Apriori {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String dataset = "/Users/andrew/workspace/Movies/src/data/tagsfinal.arff";
    DataSource dsource = new DataSource(dataset);
    Instances dapriori = dsource.getDataSet();


    Apriori apriori = new Apriori();
     apriori.buildAssociations(dapriori);

    System.out.println(apriori);
  }
}
```

From looking at several implementations across the web this seems to be a widely accepted method of doing this however i receive an error on the "apriori.buildAssociations"  line telling me that the method is undefined for the type Apriori. Furthermore, the import statement i use for the associations only works as the package type and when trying to extend it to :

```
import weka.associations.Apriori;
```

this throws an error message that "The import weka.associations.Apriori conflicts with a type defined in the same file". I have scoured StackOverflow alongside other resources and realize there is a lot of type undefined questions out there however have yet to find a solution to this problem. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is also named `Apriori`, so you are experiencing a name clash.

You should change the name of your own class to a different name (e.g. `AprioriTest`). In the unprobable case where you would really need your class to be named `Apriori`, then you would have to refer to the library's implementation by it's full name:

```
weka.associations.Apriori apriori = new weka.associations.Apriori();
apriori.buildAssociations(dapriori);
```